# Gridelements - TYPO3 10.4 with Fluidtemplates

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x, tx-gridelements

I don't know what I do wrong, I just want to have a file-based setup for my gridelements which is not deprecated.

1. Setup my layouts in tsconfig
2. Setup typoscript and link tsconfig with fluidtemplates
3. Setup the fluidtemplates

I spend already too much time trying to understand how it works together - there are so many outdated examples there.

I can add a grid layout in tsconfig and it shows in the TYPO3 backend but i doesn't render it in the frontend, no errors shown.

Here is what i got so far.

**layouts.tsconfig**

```
tx_gridelements {
    overruleRecords = 1
    setup {
        1 {
            title = One Column
            description = One Column Container
            topLevelLayout = 0
            iconIdentifier = 
            frame = 1
            config {
                colCount = 1
                rowCount = 1
                rows {
                    1 {
                        columns {
                            1 {
                                name = Content
                                colPos = 101
                                allowed = *
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**gridelements.typoscript**

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1 >
tt_content.gridelements_pi1 = COA
tt_content.gridelements_pi1 {
    #10 =< lib.stdheader
    20 = COA
    20 {
        10 = USER
        10 {
            userFunc = tx_gridelements_view->main
            setup {
                onecol < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
                onecol {
                    cObject = FLUIDTEMPLATE
                    cObject {
                        file = EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Extensions/Gridelements/Templates/Onecol.html
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some more information? TYPO3 version, Gridelements version and which of the Gridelements static templates you included would be nice to know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the static TypoScript `Gridelements w/DataProcessing` in your Template.  Or you can customize it: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/gridelements/stable/Chapters/DataProcessing/Index.html.
Then put a fluid template in your template folder named the same as the key of the layout. e.g.

```
...
setup {
    onecolumn {
        title = One Column
...
```

means your Template should be named: `Onecolumn.html`